# How to refresh the plot after adjusting radio button and slider?

Tags: r, shiny

For a shiny app I'm working on, I'm expecting the histogram will refresh after the user adjust the slider as well as the radio button.

> How could I link the radio button and the slider with the plot?

I've tried using `filter()` and it always ends up the plot not appearing when the radio button adjust to "yes" or "no". However, when the radio button stays at "All" the plot appears well.

Below is the `server.r`, I've used:

```
plotdata<- reactive({
    if(input$DayTrade=="All")
        {dataset %>%
         filter(dataset$INVEST<=input$INVEST[2],
               dataset$INVEST>=input$INVEST[1],
               dataset$Age<=input$Age[2],
               dataset$Age>=input$Age[1],dataset$DayTrade==dataset$DayTrade)}
    else if (input$DayTrade=="No")
        {dataset %>%
         filter(dataset$INVEST<=input$INVEST[2],
               dataset$INVEST>=input$INVEST[1],
               dataset$Age<=input$Age[2],
               dataset$Age>=input$Age[1],dataset$DayTrade=="No")}
    else 
        {dataset %>%
         filter(dataset$INVEST<=input$INVEST[2],
                dataset$INVEST>=input$INVEST[1],
                dataset$Age<=input$Age[2],
                dataset$Age>=input$Age[1],dataset$DayTrade=="Yes")}

})
output$histogramplot<-renderPlot({
  datos<-plotdata()
  ggplot(datos, aes(factor(Age),fill=factor(SEX))) + geom_bar(bins=15)  
})
```

Below is the `ui.r`, I've used:

```
tabPanel("no-Eaccount",sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      sliderInput("INVEST","Invest Range:",min = 0,max = 5000,value = c(100,300),pre="$"),
      sliderInput("Age","Age Range:",min = 0,max = 100,value = c(20,30)),
      radioButtons("DayTrade", "Day Trade:",
                   choices = c("Yes", "No","All"),
                   selected = "All")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      div(plotOutput("histogramplot"),style="width:100%")         
    )
    ))
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can use [eventReactive](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/observeEvent.html) to listen on radiobutton and slider and reacted when they changed. here an example

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(4,
           radioButtons("x", "Value x", choices = c('5'=5,'7'=7,'8'=8), selected = 5),
           sliderInput("y", "Value y", value = 7,6,10)
    ),
    column(8, tableOutput("table"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, sessio) {
    # Take an action every time button is pressed;
    # here, we just print a message to the console
    observeEvent(input$x, {
      cat("Showing", input$x, "rows\n")
    })
    # Take a reactive dependency on input$x or input$y, but
    # not on any of the stuff inside the function
    df <- eventReactive(as.numeric(input$x) | input$y, {
      data.frame(x=input$x,y=input$y)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df()
    })
  }
)
```